# How to filter out non-json documents in MarkLogic?

Tags: javascript, json, marklogic, mlcp, marklogic-corb

I have a lot of data loaded in my database where some of the documents loaded are not JSON files & just binary files. Correct data looks like this: "/foo/bar/1.json" but the incorrect data is in the format of "/foo/bar/*". Is there a mechanism in MarkLogic using JavaScript where I can filter out this junk data and delete them?
PS: I'm unable to extract files with mlcp that have a "?" in the URI and maybe when I try to reload this data I get this error. Any way to fix that extract along with this?

Answer (score 0):

If all of the document URIs contain a `?` and are in that directory, then you could use [`cts.uriMatch()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.uriMatch)

```
declareUpdate();
for (const uri of cts.uriMatch('/foo/bar/*?*') ) {
  xdmp.documentDelete(uri)  
}
```

Alternatively, if you are looking to find the `binary()` documents, you can apply the `format-binary` option to a [`cts.search()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.search) with a [`cts.directoryQuery()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.directoryQuery) and then delete them.

```
declareUpdate();
for (const doc of cts.search(cts.directoryQuery("/foo/bar/"), ['format-json']) ) {
  xdmp.documentDelete(fn.baseUri(doc));
}
```

They are probably being persisted as binary because there is no file extension when the URI ends with a question mark and some querystring parameter values i.e. `1.json?foo=bar` instead of `1.json`

It is difficult to diagnose and troubleshoot without seeing what your MLCP job configs are and knowing more about what you are doing to load the data.